# How to Adjust a JScrollPane based on the JTable's size?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, preferredsize

I have a table right now that's displaying a list of classes and everything works fine except the formatting of it inside of the scroll pane. Here's what I have right now for it.

```
    String[] columns = {"Class","Period","Size", "Honors/AP"};
    JTable classTable = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {}, columns));
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)classTable.getModel();

    //populating the table based on the number of classes that the teacher has
    for (Class c: t.getClasses()) {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{c.getClassName(),c.getPeriod(),c.getSize(),c.isHonorsAP()});
    }
    if (classTable.getRowCount()==0)
        model.addRow(new Object[]{});

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(classTable);
    classTable.setPreferredSize(new  Dimension(700,100));
    classTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(classTable.getPreferredSize());
    classTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    if (classTable.getPreferredSize().getHeight() < scrollPane.getPreferredSize().getHeight())
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(classTable.getPreferredSize());
```

So the problem on one end is that when there aren't enough rows to fill the preferred size of the table, it leaves extra space at the bottom and I'm trying to get that removed.

And then on the other end, when there are more rows that can fit, I need the size to stay but add in the scroll bar.
I'm really confused right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you're overthinking the issue, why do you care when the table doesn't fill the scroll pane? If it's "really" important to you, have a look at [`JTable#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize `](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize-java.awt.Dimension-) - but I have to tell you, screwing with these tends to make things worse

Comment: i mean yeah that's not as big of an issue i'll leave it if need be but when there are extra row my scroll bar isn't working and that actually makes a difference because i can't reach the lower rows

Comment: I would start by removing all the `setPreferredXxx` method calls, let the API deal with itself.  There is very rarely a reason to call these methods directly